# Conditional initial page in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using jQuery mobile with PhoneGap, and would like to show a login page the first time the app is used, and show the index page on subsequent loads.

My current solution is to use the following on deviceready

```
if(!localStorage.registered){ 
   $.mobile.changePage( "#login", { transition: "none"} ); 
}
```

However, my issue with this is that you still *see* the page transition. I would like the login page to be the first page that is visible.

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: I dont know phonegap but does this work? `webView.loadUrl("yourpage#login");` instead of line you have inside `if` stmt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Q is a few months old, it remains unanswered, I don't have any experience with phone gap but I do jQM, so I figured this may help.

I current employ a solution to this on my app by delaying auto initialisation of jQM. 
This is an example of how you could based loosely on how my application does it.

```
(function() {

  #stop jQM from auto initialising
  $(document).on("mobileinit",function() {
    $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
  });

  var my_app = new MyApp();

  # custom afterinit event is triggered on the app instance 
  $(my_app).on('afterinit',function() {
    var initial = 'login';
    if(localStorage.registered) {
      initial = 'home';
    }
    # set the page hash to our start page
    window.location.hash = initial;

    #initialise jQM
    $.mobile.initializePage();
  });

})();
```

Make sure you secure the thing that decides if login is allowed, in my application I have a data structure that is required by the app ajax in to `MyApp.appdata` it will only be there if login was actually successful.

Comment: This is similar to what I ended up doing, but I'll give you the accepted answer since you documented it :) thanks!

Comment: Glad you managed it in the end, I figured you probably would have but yeh just for others as a reference as a possible solution. have a nice day.

Comment: I try to do the same thing with jqm, and I don't understand the  `var my_app = new MyApp()` line... Nor the custom event...

Comment: Hi Matthieu, what don't you understand about it? It's simply creating a new instance of a class which is the app that i wrote which uses jqm we listen for the custom event which is triggered when the app has done various setup things, your app will likely be implemented differently, the handler for the event then tells jqm to initialise itself. Maybe link us to a version illustrating the problem you're having?

Comment: You need to trigger the custom event in your app when your app has finished doing what it needs to do for initialisation.  `$(this).trigger('afterinit')`

Comment: Hi @Rob where in the javascript code do you place this piece of code?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution may be to have a proxy page.
A different approach that I employed on another app.

An initial "loading" step, which is just a dummy page.
Make a page in your doc as the first page, eg.

```
<div id="loading" data-role="page">Loading</div>
```

in the mobileinit step bind to the pageshow event.

```
$(document).on("mobileinit",function() {
  $('#loading').on('pageshow',function() {

    # ...
    # do login check here
    # ...

    var initial = 'login';
    if(localStorage.registered) {
      initial = 'home';
    }
    # change to our initial page
    $.mobile.changePage(initial);
  });

});
```

Comment: changePage is not working when `$.mobile.autoInitializePage = false`

Answer (score 0):

What about hiding #registration and #login then do:

```
if(localStorage.registered){ 
    $('#login').show(); 
} else {
    $('#registration').show();
}
```